# Bitcoin Core Vs Daemon (Windows 10)

Tags: json-rpc, daemon

I assume that if I've Bitcoin installed locally and I either run the GUI or the Daemon... It's the same wallet, data?

To that end, if I want to use the RPC interface, can i just use the GUI while developing (I like that at alerts on any action) rather than the daemon?

TL:DR: is the RPC 8332 port active when using the GUI, Vs the Daemon?

Answer (score 1):

> It's the same wallet, data?

This depends on your configuration like `-datadir`. This can be specified by command line, or something like a registry key value (when you are using Microsoft Windows).

Note that recent versions of Bitcoin Core supports loading multiple wallet at same time.

> TL:DR: is the RPC 8332 port active when using the GUI, Vs the Daemon?

Yes, of course both `bitcoin-qt` and `bitcoind` supports JSON-RPC.

Edit: My apologies. For `bitcoin-qt` GUI, to enable JSON-RPC you must specify `-server=1` in command line options, or edit `bitcoin.conf` to add `server=1` to it. For command-line `bitcoind`, JSON-RPC is enabled by default. Thanks for Pieter Wuille for pointing this out.

Comment: You need to start `bitcoin-qt` with the `-server=1` command-line option (or put `server=1` in bitcoin.conf) in order to enable JSON-RPC access. For `bitcoind` it is enabled by default.