# Where does Bitcoin Core save the custom directory setting?

Tags: windows, bitcoin.conf, datadir

When installing Bitcoin Core on Windows 10 and starting it for the first time, the Welcome message prompts to specify a custom data directory. When specifying that custom directory, where does Bitcoin Core save that info? It cannot be on the custom directory otherwise how would it know to look for the custom directory if that info is within said directory?

Also, when going to Settings > Options > Enable RPC server, where is that setting saved? The bitcoin.conf file is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin Core Vs Daemon (Windows 10)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96490/bitcoin-core-vs-daemon-windows-10)  or [Where is the configuration file of Bitcoin-Qt kept?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/11190/13866). See Regedit Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Bitcoin\Bitcoin-Qt